# Jetty deploy war file (Automatic Deployment is not working)

Tags: eclipse, servlets, deployment, jetty, war

this is my first time deploying a war File to a Jetty Server via SCP+SSH and I'm not able to get it to work.

I made a proper .war file with Eclipse (but I also tested the same things I'm going to mention with a example .war file) and copied the file to the folder `/jetty/webapps/ROOT`. Now when I restart Jetty and try to get on the server `(I tried Serveradress/WarFilename/ aswell)` I get to a Directory Path and I'm able to download the war file but nothing else.

I also tried to copy the war file to the webapps folder itself instead of webapps/ROOT. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *directory* `${jetty.base}/webapps/ROOT/` is for exploded webapps, or static resource deployments.

If you want to serve your war file, say `myapp.war` on the root context `"/"`, then copy it to the *file* `${jetty.base}/webapps/ROOT.war`

Note: if you are copying the file into the `jetty-distribution/webapps`/ you are doing it wrong, go read up on how `${jetty.base}` and `${jetty.home}` work.

Comment: how do you find `{jetty.base}`?